# Repopulate / Refresh <select asp-items> dropdown list

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on an ASP.NET web app. In my MvcController.cs-class I have a list as follows:

```
// Instantiates an API which provides functionality.
public static readonly Api _api = ApiHandler.GetApi();

/// <summary>
/// Provides dropdown values for selecting a capture device.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<string> CaptureDevices = _api.GetCaptureDeviceIds();
```

In my Index.cshtml (view) I have the following div-element, which makes use of the asp-item tag-helper to fill the dropdown-list with values from above mentioned list "CaptureDevices":

```
<div class="input-group" id="myDiv">
    <select asp-items="@(new SelectList(MvcController.CaptureDevices))" 
        id="ddlCaptureDevices" title="<i class='fas fa-filter'></i> Select...">
    </select></div>
```

The dropdown is populated on the first startup of the website. I have a button which calls the API in order to update the list of capture devices:

```
<button type="button" id="btnUpdateListOfCaptureDevices"><i class="fas fa-retweet"></i> Update Devices</button>
```

In Javascript, I am using an AJAX call to update the list of capture devices:

```
window.$("#btnUpdateListOfCaptureDevices").click(function () {
    // perform AJAX call...
    window.$.ajax({
    // ...
    });
}
```

At the moment, I have to reload the whole website (Index.cshtml) via F5 in order to get the dropdown-list values updated.

Is there any way, to update the `asp-items="@(new SelectList(MvcController.CaptureDevices))"` on button click without having to reload the whole website?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do that; it's simple enough to remove and rebuild the list from an AJAX data source:

```
$.ajax({ 
  .
  .
  success: function(d) {
        $ddl = $("#ddlCaptureDevices");
        $ddl.empty();
        $ddl.append($("<option/>").val("value").html("text"));
```

I don't know what your datasource looks like so I can't write a better example.  I also didn't chain the jQuery methods together just to better illustrate what could happen in this process.